# How to configure my local cache on the server

Tags: java, caching

I am trying to configure a cache on my server to avoid having to hit the database all of the time. The issue I am facing is controlling what is cached.

My cache will be keyed by the users id (a string) so thats half of the battle! The value of the map needs to be a set of Personal Details( i call them cards). Personal card is the super class, then there are business and social cards. A user can have **only** one personal card, one social card but can have multiple business cards.

Therfore, is there some way to say a Map values but enforce some integrity saying only one of this one of that and as many of the other?

Or if not a Map, then maybe a list of cards with the integrity preserved.

Thanks for your time

Comment: are you using third party cache?

Comment: no - i was going to make my own local cache

Answer (score 0):

Those constraints should be handled elsewhere. In your code design, in the database, using a validation framework, or better in all of them. The cache should mirror frequently used data. If such redundancies appear in it, there might already be something wrong.